# Excel VBScript: String issue

Tags: excel, vba

After entering any characters, the value which is stored in variable A is "0". Can anyone please assist me where I am going wrong as it is working fine if I enter number

## Rookie

```
Public Sub MyFirstProgram()

 Dim A As String
 A = Val(InputBox("Enter your name", "NAME"))
 MsgBox "My name is " & A

End Sub
```

Comment: remove VAL and it will work, since A is a string (text), not a value(number) . Also you could do it without variable : `msgbox "My name is " & InputBox("Enter your name", "NAME")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Val` function converts a string to a `Double` numeric type.

Presumably, the names you are entering cannot be converted to a valid number, so the result is `0`.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/HV080557263.aspx

> The Val function stops reading the string at the first character it can't recognize as part of a number.

So if you do something like `=Val("123steve")` it will return the numeric component: `123`, but if you do `=Val("Ebeneezer Scrooge")` it stops, per the above remark -- since *no* characters have been converted to numeric value, it returns `0`.

Comment: Thank you for clearing the doubt. Can you suggest me what should be used to resolve the above issue?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. There is no issue, other than what is most likely improper use of the `Val` function.  If you are having trouble, it might be helpful to provide some examples of the input and desired output.

Comment: I want to fetch a string through input box or may be through any other way.

Comment: The input box returns a string without using the `Val` function.